# How to merge two branches from two different remotes in Git

Tags: git

I come cross some cases about branch merging but it seems like most cases are about merging branches in the same remote.

So my question is that does it matter when the two remotes are actually in different remotes?

For example, given remoteA/branchA and remoteB/branchB, I would like to merge the changes from branchA to branchB.

In my local, I could just checkout remoteB/branchB, then merge remoteA/branchA into remoteB/branchB, then push branchB? Is that correct?

Comment: *"Is that correct?"* -- try it and see if you get what you want.

Comment: I would like to know my concept is correct. This is a public environment and I am worried about making some mistakes which interfere others.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this question asks whether i am correct or not, just that which is easily verifiable by running the steps.

Comment: Your local environment is yours and only yours. You don't have to _push_ anything. Do anything you want locally and push to remote only when you are satisfied of the result. You can always undo your local operations (with a little care) or you can start over.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. That is correct.

Remote branches are just branches, same as local branches.
Same goes for remote branches from different remotes.

And in Git you can merge any branch to any other branch.

Answer (score 1):

Difference between local branch and remote branch:

A **local branch** is a branch that only you (the local user) can see. It exists only on your local machine.

A **remote branch** is a branch on a remote location (in most cases origin) where other users can track it.

To answer your question:

It does not matter when the two remotes are in different remotes. Merging works the same for any kind of branch. You should be able to merge any branch  even if one is local and the other one is remote.